# Nested JSON in WebAPI using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, json

I need to only use stored procedure and NOT Linq in Entity Framework to generate nested JSON. Here is the JSON I want to create

```
{
    "quiz" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "name" :"Guess Fruit Color",
        "description": "You need to guess color of fruits",
        "questions" : [
            {"id" : 1000 , "quizId" : 1 , "description": "The color of apple is" , "options" : [
                          {"id" : 1 , "questionId" : 1000 , "description" : "Green", "correctAnswer" : false },
                          {"id" : 2 , "questionId" : 1000 , "description" : "Red",   "correctAnswer" : true },
                          {"id" : 3 , "questionId" : 1000 , "description" : "Pink",  "correctAnswer" : false },
                          {"id" : 4 , "questionId" : 1000 , "description" : "Purple", "correctAnswer": false }      
            ]
            },
            {"id" : 1001 , "quizId" : 1 , "description": "The color of mangoss is" , "options" : [
                          {"id" : 5 , "questionId" : 1001 , "description" : "Green", "correctAnswer" : false },
                          {"id" : 6 , "questionId" : 1001 , "description" : "Red",   "correctAnswer" : false },
                          {"id" : 6 , "questionId" : 1001 , "description" : "Yello", "correctAnswer" : true },
                          {"id" : 8 , "questionId" : 1001 , "description" : "Purple", "correctAnswer": false }      
            ]
            }      
        ]}
    ]
}
```

My stored procedure is just returning flat data and I am not not sure how to convert it into hierarchical data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetQuizDetails
As
    SELECT 
            Quiz.Id,
            Quiz.name,
            Quiz.description,

            --Questions 
            Questions.Id,
            Questions.TriviaQuizId,
            Questions.description,

            --Options 
            Options.id,
            Options.questionId,
            Options.description,
            Options.correctAnswer



    FROM        
            dbo.TriviaQuizs as Quiz 
            JOIN dbo.TriviaQuestions as Questions on Quiz.id = Questions.TriviaQuizId
            JOIN dbo.TriviaOptions as Options on Options.questionId = Questions.Id
```

I have designed my class like

```
public class TriviaQuiz
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        //A Quiz can have many questions
        public virtual List<TriviaQuestion> questions { get; set; }
    }

public class TriviaQuestion
    {
        [Key(), ForeignKey("triviaQuiz")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property to set foreign key relationship
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual TriviaQuiz triviaQuiz { get; set; }

       //A question can have many options 
        public virtual List<TriviaOption> options { get; set; }
    }

public class TriviaOption
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("triviaQuestion")]
        //Tell EF That questionId is a Foreign key to TriviaQuestion table
        public int questionId { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Boolean correctAnswer { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property to set up Foreign key relation ship
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual TriviaQuestion triviaQuestion { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help and direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? this AFAIK can be done on SQL 2016, in prior versions you can generate an XML from the database and then try to parse it to JSON with C#

Comment: We are using SQL server 2008.

Comment: This MSDN article explains how you can save the Json data using stored procedures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
I know its an older post, but hope it helps!
Note: OpenJSON requires the compatibility mode of the Database to be 130.